# How does role-hierarchy work for user/manager role

Tags: role-hierarchy

I would like to understand how role hierarchy works in SF as I have tried a few settings but somehow the role hierarchy is not respecting the record level access although the record level access is set to private.

A question related to how users are setup in SF, that am hoping one of you guys can help point in the right direction (need this in the context of a requirement I am building out)….

How do I meet the following requirement on any SF org?
(a) I have user-1, user-2, Principal-1 & Principal-2
(b) User-1 reports to Principal-1 & User-2 reports into Principal-2
(c) So if User-1 creates a record, we want Principal-1 to automatically get access to that record. But Principal-2 should not have access to that record in theory how role hierarchy in private mode should work. Courtesy: Controlling Access Using Hierarchies (salesforce.com)

What I have tried and it did not work is below.

1. I created these 4 users in SF (Setup  Users). When doing this:
   a.  I did not specify any value for the “Role” field on the User record
   b.  I did specify the “Manager” value on the User record – setting Principal-1 as User-1’s manager, and Principal-2 as User-2’s manager
   c.  RESULT: As User-1, I created a record. As Principal-1, I am not able to access this new record
   d.  Based on the SF doc, it did indicate that the User’s Manager by itself does not have any impact on data visibility/access.
2. To overcome this limitation, I crated a role hierarchy – created a role “Role_USR” whose parent role in role hierarchy is “Role_PRIN”. I updated User-1/2’s user records to have their role as Role_USR, and the Principal-1/2’s user records now have their role as Role_PRIN

a.  RESULT: As Principal-1, I am able to access the record created by User-1.

However, now Principal-2 user is also able to access this record.

What do we need to do here in the above use case where Principal-2 user is restricted to access the record created by user-1, who reports to principal-1.

Answer (score 1):

> the User’s Manager by itself does not have any impact on data visibility/access.

Correct.

> User-1/2’s user records to have their role as Role_USR, and the Principal-1/2’s user records now have their role as Role_PRIN

> a. RESULT: As Principal-1, I am able to access the record created by User-1. However, now Principal-2 user is also able to access this record.

This is the expected behavior (and you'll also find that Principal-1 can access records owned by User-2). This is because the Users and the Principals *share roles*, which means they also share role-based record access.

If you want visibility to roll up differently, you'll need more Roles. User 1 could have the Role "Service User", for example, and Principal 1 the Role "Service Manager", while User 2 has "Sales User" and Principal 2 "Sales Manager". Provided the "User" roles are under their corresponding "Manager" roles in the hierarchy, you'll get the visibility you're looking for - and so long as the "Manager" roles are *siblings* of each other, they won't be able to see each other's subordinates' records.

With the role hierarchy, remember that visibility works by roles, *not* by individual users. The reporting hierarchy of the personnel is irrelevant.